# About TAP in libcouchbase

Tags: c, couchbase

I've seen "TAP" from couchbase document. I do kind of understand what it does, however it is hard to find any examples using TAP Apis. It would be great if you could expalin what TAP is exactly and how it can be used + any example source will be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

TAP is an internal API used by Couchbase for moving data around the cluster. There are a few tools that use it as well.

One use case would be to view all updates on the cluster as they occur. This can perhaps be better accomplished with some of the code in our Elastic Search adapter (in Java):

https://github.com/couchbaselabs/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase

Or there is a project to provide a changed feed in Ruby: https://github.com/scalabl3/couchbase-xdcr-sinatra